# Is it possible to set the content disposition of an existing Azure blob?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Based on stimms answer here:
[Azure Storage API ContentDisposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719641/azure-storage-api-contentdisposition)

and the information found here:
[Friendly filename when public download Azure blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027656/friendly-filename-when-public-download-azure-blob)

I have been able to set the content disposition when uploading new files. But I also would like to be to able to set the content disposition of existing files.

```
blob.Properties.ContentDisposition = string.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"", friendlyName);
```

works fine when set before uploading a file, but has no effect if I try it on an existing blob.

Is is just plain impossible to change the content disposition of an existing blob or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. You just have to call `SetProperties()` method on the blob after you set `ContentDisposition`. So your code should be:

```
            blob.FetchAttributes();//Fetch properties first so that you don't overwrite existing properties when you call SetProperties
            blob.Properties.ContentDisposition = string.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"", friendlyName);
            blob.SetProperties();
```