# How to download the Azure blob content with the same name of File

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure storage account where I have created a folder to upload & download a file in it.I am also performing the rename operation on it e.g when I perform rename operation and upload the file into the blob all Blob metadata get updated successfully.

Please suggest the changes.

Comment: Can you please check the value of `Content-Disposition` property of the blob? My guess is that it's value is set as `attachment; filename="bootstrap.min.css"`.

Comment: Please use Microsoft' Azure Storage Explorer or any other Azure storage management tool. You should be able to see that property. I don't think portal exposes this property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to download the Azure blob content with the same name of File

As  Gaurav Mantri said that you could specify the `ContentDisposition` property for your blob. Use the [Azure Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer), you could quick set the `ContentDisposition` property as follows:

[image]

But when I downloading the image, the `ContentDisposition` seems not working at all. Then I found a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719641/azure-storage-api-contentdisposition), you need to set the `DefaultServiceVersion` for your blob storage service. And you need to write your code and set the `DefaultServiceVersion`, more details you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs) and choose your development language.

**Test:**

[image]

Additionally, if you upload/download your blob files by programming, you could refer to [issue1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227608/is-it-possible-to-the-content-disposition-of-an-existing-azure-blob) and [issue2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027656/friendly-filename-when-public-download-azure-blob).