# Assigning a friendly name to an Azure download

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have looked at the question asked here: 
[Friendly filename when public download Azure blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027656/friendly-filename-when-public-download-azure-blob)
I am a total azure noob and wouldn't have a clue how to implement any of the answers except this one which looks like something I could handle:

```
string sasBlobToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(sharedPolicy, new SharedAccessBlobHeaders()
        {
            ContentDisposition = "attachment; filename=" + friendlyFileName
        });


string downloadLink = blob.Uri + sasBlobToken;
```

My question is how to set the 'sharedpolicy variable correctly?  I tried just making a blank one on the line above:

```
SharedAccessBlobPolicy sharedpolicy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
```

But I get a permission denied message when clicking the download link. So my question is how to set the sharedpolicy variable correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because you are not setting any permissions and permission expiry in your `SharedAccessBlobPolicy`. Try the following:

```
            SharedAccessBlobPolicy sharedpolicy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
            {
                Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,//Read permission because you want to download the file
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1))//The link will expire after 1 hour
            };
            string sasBlobToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(sharedPolicy, new SharedAccessBlobHeaders()
                    {
                        ContentDisposition = "attachment; filename=" + friendlyFileName
                    });


            string downloadLink = blob.Uri + sasBlobToken;
```

Comment: Fantastic, it works!  Who knew a little bit of code could make someone so happy! :)  Sorry I can't upvote your answer but I don't have priveliges yet.

Comment: Glad to know that it worked! You could just accept the answer :)...dont worry about upvoting it.