# Download Private Blob Image using Proxy?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I currently access images on my website through a **public** blob url:

```
https://subscription_name.blob.core.windows.net/users/5/drivers_licence.jpg
```

I want to change the blob access from public to **private** and aceess the url as:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/5/drivers_licence.jpg
```

The Blob Url is stored and pulled from the database so I can run a query to update all records with the new prefix (localhost one), that's the easy bit.

The question is: how can I implement the Proxy so that when I click the download link, it opens up the document in a blank page with the new localhost url?

The localhost is just for testing purposes. I will eventually replace this with my domain name:

```
https://website-name.com/users/5/drivers_licence.jpg
```

**Later Edit** I figured it out, I posted the solution as an answer below

Comment: Can you please explain why you want to change the URL? Why can't you  serve the blob directly from storage?

Comment: Security. The file may contain sensitive information and I don't want other users to see the image (I don't want the info to be accessible through the blob URL). Also, I don't want to expose the blob host, which is why I want to replace it with my own domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I was looking for, in case someone else is looking for a similar solution:

```
public class BlobController : ApiController {

    private readonly BlobHelper helper = new BlobHelper();

    [Route("api/blob/{container}/{*filename}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage BlobDownload(string container, string filename) {
        var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();

        // 1) check if parameters are set

        // 2) try and get the blob
        var blob = helper.DownloadBlob(container, filename);

        // 3) check the response to see if blob actually exists

        // 4) return the file
        httpResponseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        httpResponseMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(blob.Stream);
        // don't forget to set the content type, this is important in order to mimic the described behaviour (IE: display an image in the browser)
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(blob.ContentType); 

        return httpResponseMessage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're concerned about security and want to keep the container's ACL as private (which BTW is absolutely right thing to do), what you could do is create a [`Shared Access Signature (SAS)`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/) on the blob with `Read` permission and short expiry. To further secure the SAS, you can apply IP ACL on SAS. With IP ACL, even if the user shares the SAS URL with other user, the other user will not be able to  access the URL if the IP address is different than the one configured in SAS.

If you're concerned about not exposing the storage account endpoint, you can map a custom domain to your blob storage endpoint as mentioned by @forester123.

If you want to serve the blobs through your website domain, the only solution is to download the blob first from storage on your web server and then serve the blob from there. Taking your example, I am assuming the container name is `users` and there you have virtual folders for each user. What you would need to do in this case is create a folder in your website called `users` and download the blobs there and save them as local files. Once the files are saved, they should be accessible via your website URL.

However I would not recommend this approach because it is not efficient. You would need to first download the blob from storage to your local server and serve  it from there. Furthermore, each server will have a limit on how much local data you can save and if you don't constantly clean up the files, you may run out of disk space.

My recommendation would be to look at Shared Access Signature. You can read more about it here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/.

Comment: Thanks for replying. What I'm really looking for is related to a paragraph I found on another topic (also related to your 3rd paragraph here), it was labeled **Proxy Download**. Please have a look at the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027656/friendly-filename-when-public-download-azure-blob  So far I've tried downloading the file to a MemoryStream in my API controller, then I am returning the object as Task<HttpResponseMessage>. I can just use javascript to return the file in the browser, but instead of saving the file I want it opened in a new tab via the new url

Comment: Opening up the image in the new tab would mean a second request to your website and for that you would need to save the file somewhere  on your server so that the browser can find the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try configure a custom domain name for your Blob storage endpoint, check details [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-custom-domain-name/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am aware of this, but it's not exactly what I need. I think I am looking for an example for the accepted answer here (third heading - **Proxy Download**): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027656/friendly-filename-when-public-download-azure-blob

Comment: @Toonsylvania thanks, I think I misunderstood you and thus the answer is not what you want, I'll keep digging and update my answer if I get any solution. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you, no need to apologize, any help will be much welcomed :)